# SQL in Oracle - missing select key word & parentheses

Tags: sql, oracle, ddl

So I'm currently writing in SQL for my assessment and this error keeps appearing (Missing select key word as well as missing parentheses)

Here is what I have been entering into Oracle:

```
CREATE TABLE Customers
(Abstract VARCHAR2(400),
Author VARCHAR2(40) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (CustomerID),
LastName,
FirstName,
Address,
City,
Delivery address,
Phone number,
Email address,
Credit limit varchar(255),
Balance owing varchar(255),
Sales,
Sales person,
PRIMARY KEY (CUST_ID));
```

I'm a beginner at this so that is why I don't understand what is missing.

Comment: `Delivery address` ... you can't have spaces in a column name without escaping, also there is no type specified.

Comment: You are defining two PK; besides you are missing the types of some columns

Comment: What is escaping?  And type? also thank you I didn't realize I had two primary keys.

Comment: @Tim:still waiting for the OP of the other question to accept your answer, your turn now  :). Lilac: you should first decide what your PK should be, then remove spaces from column names and decide the type of each field; this will guide you to solve

Comment: @Lilac.Galaxy Use double quotes to escape column names with spaces,e .g. `"Delivery Address" VARCHAR(55)`

Answer (score 1):

You really need to start with "how to create a table" at https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/tables003.htm.
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_7002.htm

For time being am posting the correct create table definition, but you really need to read the doc and correlate how the below code is working.

```
CREATE TABLE Customers (
    Abstract VARCHAR2(400),
    Author VARCHAR2(40) NOT NULL,
    CustomerID number PRIMARY KEY,
    LastName VARCHAR2(40),
    FirstName VARCHAR2(40),
    Address VARCHAR2(400),
    City VARCHAR2(40),
    Delivery_address VARCHAR2(400),
    Phone NUMBER,
    Email_address VARCHAR2(40),
    Credit VARCHAR(255),
    Balance_owing VARCHAR(255),
    Sales VARCHAR2(40),
    Sales_person VARCHAR2(40)
);
```